# Getting the weights to compare AMORE NN models?

Tags: r, modeling

I'm using the AMORE NN package to build multiple models from the same training set and i want to compare the weights between the models.

I'm pretty much an R newbie, but some of the stronger R users I know can't answer either.

here's the code:

```
library("AMORE")
net <- newff(n.neurons=c(104,200,104), learning.rate.global=1e-2, 
             momentum.global=0.5,error.criterium="LMS", Stao=NA,    
             hidden.layer="tansig",output.layer="purelin", 
             method="ADAPTgdwm")
result <- train(net, x, y, error.criterium="LMS", 
                report=TRUE, show.step=50, n.shows=20 )
```

`net` is pretty easy to break out into some functions and I think input weights.

`net$neurons` is where all the layer weights are.  `net$neurons` is a or list of length 304.  `net$neurons[n]` will print out what appears to be a set of units from the model. But it contains many things and I can't seem to get them out short of cut and paste.

I won't paste it all here - my model is pretty big as you can see and it goes on for several pages, but just to give you an idea:

> net$neurons[1]
>
> $type
>
> [1] "output"
>
> $activation.function
>
> [1] 3
>
> $output.links
>
> [1] NA
>
> $output.aims
>
> [1] 103
>
> $input.links
>     [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
>    [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
>    [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
>    [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
>    [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
>    [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
>   [109] 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
>   [127] 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
>   [145] 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
>   [163] 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
>   [181] 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198
>   [199] 199 200
>
> $weights
>     [1]  7.767180e-03 -5.118608e-03  4.683484e-03  6.499882e-03  6.897404e-04
>     [6]  4.169454e-03 -5.282092e-05  9.589098e-04  7.031523e-03  6.669872e-03
>    [11]  2.716605e-03 -4.188492e-04 -4.141848e-03 -6.576378e-03 -6.812882e-03
>    [16] -3.511420e-03 -3.091805e-04  7.128892e-03  7.160105e-03 -8.050284e-03
>    [21]  3.386642e-03  2.579751e-03  7.065484e-03  1.872059e-04  1.829110e-03
>    [26]  7.472301e-03 -8.303545e-03  7.981113e-03  3.584151e-03 -4.432509e-03
>    [31] -8.705997e-04 -7.456132e-03 -9.884449e-04  7.523373e-03 -6.673688e-03
>    [36] -9.070783e-04  3.068912e-03 -8.045977e-04 -2.165867e-03  5.507719e-03
>   ...

There's lots more, lots more, but it all has this general format.
Things that give no answer at all:

```
net$neuron[1]$weights
net$neuron[1,"weights"]
net$neuron[1,1]
net$neuron[1]["weights"]
```

probably some of the above is laughably impossible anyway, but can anyone point me somewhere useful?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

net$neuron[1][[1]][[7]]

first neuron, first list, element 7 are the weights

net$neuron[1][[1]][[8]]

element 8 is the bias

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148245)

Comment: Frederik, thank you for your post.  @Kjetil It looks like an answer to me.  (I cannot judge whether it's correct, though, so I regret being unable to upvote it.)  I think you might be reacting to fact that nowadays we would migrate this question to [SO], because it's purely a software question with a purely programming answer, as this post demonstrates.